# how to pass string values as parameter in PLSQL procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

Below is an example query that I would like my procedure to generate

```
select * 
   from Registration 
  where Loc_ID = 6 
    AND CROP_ID = 163 
    AND REG_NAME = 'Apiro MX';
```

`REG_NAME` is `varchar2()`

I have created one procedure, where I want to execute one query like below

```
query := 'select REG_ID from Registration where loc_id = ' || 
          countryid || ' AND Crop_id = ' || cropid || 
          ' AND Reg_name = '|| ''' || productid || ''' || ';
```

I am getting error in `REG_NAME` part, where it is taking `productid` as `" || productid ||"`

can you please help me with the exact query for that.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL for that query? (And if you have a real reason to, why aren't you using bind variables?)

Comment: can't we do that using dynamic sql, If it is possible can you please correct that query for me.

Comment: Of course you can, either just by escaping the quotes you're using, or (much) preferably with bind variables; but why would you want to? It's less efficient and harder to maintain.

Comment: Actually I have done many changes till now in DB and if I go with other way I need to revert those changes and consume time. Can you please correct that query for me. As I have changes many times

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use dynamic sql:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_registration (
  i_countryid IN  REGISTRATION.LOC_ID%TYPE,
  i_crop_id   IN  REGISTRATION.CROP_ID%TYPE,
  i_reg_name  IN  REGISTRATION.REG_NAME%TYPE,
  o_cursor    OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN o_cursor FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   Registration
    WHERE  Loc_ID   = i_countryid
    AND    CROP_ID  = i_crop_id
    AND    REG_NAME = i_reg_name;
END;
/
```

If you do need dynamic SQL (however, you can almost always do it without):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_registration (
  i_countryid IN  REGISTRATION.LOC_ID%TYPE,
  i_crop_id   IN  REGISTRATION.CROP_ID%TYPE,
  i_reg_name  IN  REGISTRATION.REG_NAME%TYPE,
  o_cursor    OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN o_cursor
  FOR 'SELECT *
       FROM   Registration
       WHERE  Loc_ID   = :i
       AND    CROP_ID  = :j
       AND    REG_NAME = :k'
  USING i_countryid, i_crop_id, i_reg_name;
END;
/
```

Comment: if I want to do that using dynamic sql, can it be possible? can you correct that query for me?

Comment: The original query is "correct", however, I can provide you with an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

In PLSQL you can escape quote by adding another one, therefore,
you should put double quotes around productid.
Try something like:

```
query := 'select REG_ID from Registration where loc_id = ' || 
      countryid || ' AND Crop_id = ' || cropid || 
      ' AND Reg_name = '|| '''' || productid || '''' || ';
```

Or don't use dynamic SQL and try creating stored procedure 
(check the link for the instruction).
http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-procedures.htm

Comment: This is a bad idea [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/327/) - If you don't use bind variables then users can do unexpected things like passing `productid` as `Apiro MX' AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM your_password_table WHERE passwordhash = '123456' ) AND '1' = '1`.